# File "<string>", line SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to do this exercise but fail. I can only get this result:

> ```
> main()   File "C:\Users\chemuser\Desktop\KHL\python\chapter4_6.py", line 22, in main
> asciimark = eval(line)   File "<string>", line 1
>
> ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
> ```

here is my fail code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#A certain CS professor gives 5-point quizzes that are 
#graded on the scale 5-A, 4-B, 3-C, 2-D, 1-F, 0-F.
#Write a program that accepts a quiz score as an 
#input and prints out the corresponding grade.

import string

def main():

    #set up file names
    infileName = raw_input("input file name: ")
    outfileName = raw_input("output file name: ")

    #open files
    infile = open(infileName, "r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    #process each line of the input file
    for line in infile.readlines():
        #get the mark from line
        asciimark = eval(line)
        #creat grade
        allgrade = "FEDCBA"
        grade = allgrade[asciimark]
        #write it to the output file
        outfile.write(grade+"\n")

    #close both files
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

    print "Done!"

main()
```

the input file is look like this (just a column of number 0 - 5, no blank line between):

5

1

0

2

3

I did a test, I add '/n' in the first line (5/n), it shows:

> ```
> main()   File "C:\Users\chemuser\Desktop\KHL\python\chapter4_6.py", line 22, in main
> asciimark = eval(line)   File "<string>", line 1
> 5\n
>   ^ SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
> ```

your comments are very appreciated!!

Comment: There are several better questions that you could be asking, that you should have asked before you got to this point.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the problem is solved.